# How to create a multi column table of data from the exponential distribution

Tags: r, statistics, exponential-distribution

I need to create a multi column table of customer arrival time, customer wait time, service time, and customer leave time. Service time is the time it takes for the cashier to help the customer. Arrival time and service time are provided by a function which uses the rexp command.

The table needs to look like this: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ14s.jpg)

My code looks like this:

```
singleTime = function(Rate)
{
  data = rexp(1,Rate)
  return(data)
}

waitTimes = function(m,arrivalRate,serviceRate)
{
  arrivalTimes = c(1:m)
  waitTimes = c(1:m)
  serviceTimes = c(1:m)
  leaveTimes = c(1:m)
  previousLeaveTime = 0
  for(i in (1:m))
  {
    arrivalTimes[i] = singleTime(arrivalRate)
    if(i == 0)
    {
      waitTimes[i] = 0
    }
    else if((previousLeaveTime - arrivalTimes[i])<= 0)
    {
      waitTimes[i] = 0
    }
    else
    {
      waitTimes[i] = leaveTimes[i-1] - arrivalTimes[i]
    }
    serviceTimes[i] = singleTime(serviceRate)
    leaveTimes[i] = waitTimes[i] + serviceTimes[i] + arrivalTimes[i]
    previousLeaveTime = leaveTimes[i]
    i = i + 1
  }
  waitTimesTable = table(arrivalTimes,waitTimes,serviceTimes,leaveTimes)
  View(waitTimesTable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace `View(waitTimesTable)` with `return(data.frame(arrivalTimes, waitTimes, serviceTimes, leaveTimes)`? I'm not sure how concerned you are with the look of the table.